# Webdriver.IO dragAndDrop does not correctly

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

I am trying to drag and drop element by using webdriver.io dragAndDrop function (and tried with moveToObject, buttonDown, up ... etc) and it's able to press the element but releasing it in random places, usually to the right bottom corner of the screen, not sure why that's happening. For selector I am using xpath.

I have tried also this way and still does not work.

```
browser.moveToObject('//div[2]');
browser.buttonDown();
browser.moveToObject('//div[3]');
browser.buttonUp();
```

Comment: Hi there, can you elaborate on which browser drivers you are trying to use the "dragAndDrop" command with? Not all browser drivers might support that functionality yet.

Comment: Latest Chrome on Mac